# How do you get to the Secret Room in the Tavern?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

My friend and I noticed that there seems to be an inaccessible room in the Tavern with something behind it. We saw that there was a Treasure Chest seemingly floating somewhere off the map.

[image: treasure]

In addition, if you walk up to the second floor of the Tavern and position your camera through the wall just right, you can highlight something called the Defender's Forge.
[image: through the walls]

Confirmation of the speculation was confirmed in the notes for the 7.07 patch, which had a note that said the following:

> Moved bonus-item crates back into the main section of the Halloween Tavern, out from the Secret Room.

What is this Secret Room? How do I get there? Do I need to beat the campaign first or something else?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are able to walk straight through the door of the secret room once you have beaten all the campaign maps on any difficulty.  Inside contains a bunch of easter eggs as well as the item crate you mentioned containing weapons of your 'parents'.

You'll know the door is open when the bright glowing OPEN sign above the door is lit up.

Comment: Also of note, you can not enter the room of another player.

Answer (score -1):

After you beat every level of the campaign on any difficulty you go in the room there are a bunch of pop culture references and a chest with 200,000 mana your parents weapons (moms bow, dads sword, dads staff, dads spear) a defenders forge a tv for spying and a radio to change the music.