# How can i find my TF2 familiars and portal gun on ranked?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

So when i started playing i first chose a local game. I played around abit and went to the tavern to discover my portal gun and TF2 familiars. The next day i decided to go play ranked so a made a character and went to play around abit. After going to my own tavern the familiar or gun boxes were not to be found.

So my question is how do i find them? Or get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played for a week in Open with the items, then when the halloween stuff came out I went to Trendy and was disappointed they were not there.. Then after a few days it just showed up in the middle of the tavern same as in Open. It may just take time, I am not sure. I did not do anything special that I am aware of.

Oh, They do only appear to appear in YOUR tavern (ie you are hosting), if that is a factor.

EDIT: Was reading over old patch notes and found this one listed under 7.06. Thought it might help clear up some confusion (I guess this is why mine 'appeared' after a few days :))

- Moved bonus-item crates back into the main section of the Ranked Tavern, out from the Secret Room.

Comment: +1 to they only appear in YOUR tavern. I made this mistake at first and quickly found them when I created my own game.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, the boxes will spawn inside the [Secret room](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34336/how-do-you-get-to-the-secret-room-in-the-tavern) so you may have to beat the campaign first to get your bonus pets on ranked.  This may have been done recently (I got mine a while ago and they were outside in the tavern).

[Source](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?11493-Did-not-get-my-Tf2-pets-or-Portal-gun-in-ranked)